# Source tree local changes deleted

Tags: git

I am newbie in Git so I use SourceTree. And today i accidentally double-clicked previous commit when i wanted to commit local changes, so switched branch to origin/master. Is there any way to get it back? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you had 'discard local changes' tick on - probably changes are lost, as they should be.

But if you did not - changes should still be there, just checkout needed branch using the same method and proceed